error message from compile command in Emacs 29.3
The latest Emacs update

GNU Emacs 29.3 (build 1, x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version
3.24.31, cairo version 1.16.0) of 2024-03-24

prints an error message

emacs: writing to child signal FD: Invalid argument

to the terminal (xfce4-terminal) from which it was started every time when I use the 'compile' command. It didn't do that before the update. The compilation itself works fine, but this error message annoys me.
What does it mean? The child process gets what it needs and compiles as expected. What could that 'Invalid argument' be? And what can be done about it?
PS. The error message appears also when starting Emacs from another terminal (xterm) and even when started within the terminal with the -nw option!
PPS. Same error message with 'emacs -Q -nw' from a tty without X.

Is that a complete recipe to repro the problem when starting with emacs -Q? If not, consider posting that. If yes, maybe M-x report-emacs-bug?
